# Android: Application class not recognized in Dagger2 Component

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

It seems like I cant find the `MyApplication` class from my ApplicationComponent:

[image]

And this error output:

> error: cannot find symbol class MyApplication

Here is all the related classes:

ApplicationComponent:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {ApplicationContextModule.class,
        SharedPreferencesModule.class,
        KeyStoreModule.class,
        SharedPreferenceHelperModule.class,
        StartModule.class,
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        BindModule.class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(MyApplication myApplication);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(MyApplication myApplication); //CANT FIND MYAPPLICATION
        ApplicationComponent build();
    }

    @ApplicationContext
    Context getApplicationContext();

    SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences();

    KeyStoreServiceInterface getKeyStoreService();

    SharedPreferencesHelper getSharedPreferencesHelper();

    StartViewModelFactory getStartViewModelFactory();

}
```

MyApplication class:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements HasActivityInjector {

    private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingActivityInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationContextModule(new ApplicationContextModule(this))
                .build();
        DaggerApplicationComponent
                .builder()
                .build()
                .inject(this); //ERROR HERE. Complains that there is no inject method, offers creation of one in ApplicationComponent, but already exists one.
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingActivityInjector;
    }

    public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
        return applicationComponent;
    }
}
```

And here is my manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:appComponentFactory="whateverString">
    <activity android:name="start.StartActivity" ></activity>
</application>
```

Why does it not recognize the class?

Comment: `android:name="MyApplication"` should be `android:name=".MyApplication"`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh it gives me error unresolved class and suggest class creation. I am guessing the placement of MyApplication in the folders gives me this. Is there a way to find the path?

Comment: use command+shit+f to find your class

Comment: Thanks. MyApplication is in the root folder. This should work by adding the dot, but my component still cant find it. Any more suggestions? @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: Seems like the issue can be with package name

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh It was 100% a package name issue. Moved MyApplication to a new folder and added foldername before .MyApplication and no problems anymore. Thanks for the help. Please, if you would like, post your latest comment+(the dot comment) as an answer so I can upvote&accept for if anyone else might have use of it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently looks like a package name issue as component is unable to import it or use it so

1. Move the Application class under the root package name (that you entered while creating app)
2. Use `.MyApplication` to register you application class

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

or may also add any additional package name with application name

Comment: Thanks again for the help

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding :)